# In float point numbers, why the sign bit is not next to 23-bit mantissa?

Tags: floating-point

I was taught that the 32-bit floating numbers look like this: a sign bit, 8-bit exponent, and 23-bit mantissa. 
Now in an exam, I had to rewrite a floating number to hexadecimal LE bytes; this required me to write the full number first, and then split into groups of 4. 
My question is: if the exponent has 8 bits, why is the sign bit not next to mantissa? Because in this way, I could rewrite the exponent separately, as it takes only 8 bits. Instead, I have to put the first digit of exponent into the mantissa (to make a byte), and the first 7 digits together with a sign bit. Does not make much sense to me.

Comment: The bits are in order of significance. With the sign bit in front, all of the positive floating-point numbers are in the same order as their representations: A greater representation (as a 32-bit two’s complement integer) has a greater represented value. For the negative numbers, they are in the opposite order. That is unfortunate, since it means a single integer compare instruction is insufficient to compare floating-point data, but it is the best you can do given that the representation is sign-and-magnitude, rather than some analog of two’s complement.